# SDK definition of CStatusBar::GetStatusBarCtrl

Tags: c++, mfc, statusbar

I was trying to find the underlying tooltip control that the `CStatusBar` uses but have not found it yet.

In my research of the SDK code I noticed:

```
// CStatusBar
// NOTE: The cast in GetStatusBarCtrl is ugly, but must be preserved for compatibility.
// CStatusBarCtrl is not related to CStatusBar by inheritance so we must be careful to ensure 
// that CStatusBarCtrl remains a binary compatible subset of CStatusBar.
_AFXEXT_INLINE CStatusBarCtrl& CStatusBar::GetStatusBarCtrl() const
    { return *(CStatusBarCtrl*)this; }
```

How does that actually work?! The control being one thing but returning another?

By the way, I researched further into the underlying `CStatusBarCtrl` and I still can't find the tooltip member variable.

Comment: *"How does that actually work?!"* - The answer is in the comment: *"ensure that CStatusBarCtrl remains a binary compatible subset of CStatusBar."* In other words: The virtual function table of `CStatusBarCtrl` needs to match the starting sequence of the virtual function table of `CStatusBar`. Doing that is not legal in C++, but Microsoft's compiler ensures that this works.